# R ggplot2 scales cancel each other

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm having some trouble plotting with `ggplot2`. When trying to use 2 different scale functions, they won't act at the same time, that is, only one command will actually work, depending on the order. For example, if I do `plot + scale_x_discrete(...)` and then `plot + scale_fill_discrete(...)`, only the later will work (editing the legend), while the other wont, leaving the x axis unedited. If I switch the order of commands, then the axis is edited, while the legend is neglected.

Could you please explain why this is happening and how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
plot + scale_x_discrete(...) + scale_fill_discrete(...)
```